# Is it possible to transfer data to Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, mixpanel, firebase-analytics

We are trying to migrate from MixPanel to Firebase analytics. Is there any way to transfer historic data into Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't a solution to do just that.
An alternative would be to export your firebase analytics data to Big Query, in Big Query import your data from MixPanel. However you won't be able to visualise the data imported in Big Query in the classic Firebase Dashboard, you'll need to build your custom dashboard using Google Data Studio for instance.